# Sonar maven plugin without settings.xml

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I need change the sonar url without change settings.xml, so i have the following:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.1168</version>
                <configuration>
        <sonar.host.url>http://sonar.viavarejo.com.br</sonar.host.url>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

My sonar.host.url didn't work, just ignore, see the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.1.1168:sonar (default-cli) on project myproject: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9000: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]
```

**Important:** I can't change the settings.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the URL as a property:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.host.url>http://<server>:<port>/</sonar.host.url>
</properties>
```

or directly in the command line usind

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://<server>:<port>/
```